# WebService error: the referenced element with ID '1' was not found in the document

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

What is the reason of this error in web-service method call?

```
The referenced element with ID '1' was not found in the document.
```

And what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the mistake was that I use a wep-api URL as wcf URL. Instead of adding wcf service, I added WEB-Service reference and problem solved.

The serializations in WCF and WEB-API are different so this problem occured.